# Issue while taking a backup of SQL Server database which is hosted on server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have installed a Windows application in a LAN network and deployed database on a server PC (for example PC name is 1).

Now when a user of another PC (PC name is 2) is using the application from his PC (2) and database (on PC 1).

On a button click, I want to take a database backup and store that backup on fixed path of PC 1.

Currently I am using below code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Fixed path");

DASQLBase thebase = new DASQLBase(Global.gMasterConnectionString);

List<SqlParameter> paras = new List<SqlParameter>();

paras.Add(new SqlParameter("@BackupFolderPath ", "Fixed Path"));

thebase.ExecuteSPDataTable("proc_BackupData", paras);
```

and this is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
DECLARE 
    @databasename AS NVARCHAR(128)
    , @timecomponent AS NVARCHAR(50)
    , @sqlcommand AS NVARCHAR(1000);

SET @databasename = (SELECT MIN(name) FROM sys.databases 
                     WHERE name IN ('CP001','CP002','CP003','CP004','CP005','CP006','CP007','CP008','CP009','CP010')); 
    --AND name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb'));

WHILE @databasename IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @timecomponent = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,
        GETDATE(), 120), ' ', '_'), ':', ''), '-', '');

    /*  SET @sqlcommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @databasename + ' TO DISK =
        ''C:\Backups\' + @databasename + '_' + @timecomponent + '.bak''';*/

    SET @sqlcommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @databasename + ' TO DISK =
        ''' + @BackupFolderPath  + @databasename + '_' + @timecomponent + '.bak'''

    EXEC(@sqlcommand);  

    SET @databasename = (SELECT MIN(name) FROM sys.databases 
                         WHERE name IN ('CP001','CP002','CP003','CP004','CP005','CP006','CP007','CP008','CP009','CP010')  
                           AND name > @databasename);
END
```

The problem is that database backup work if code and database running on same pc (1) but not from pc (2)

Comment: `Global.gMasterConnectionString` ... whats the path to the DB ?

Comment: It is our structure to get db string from other dll

Comment: My point was, are you sure the path is the same in both machines and accesdibke

Answer (score 0):

An instance of SQL Server runs on the machine on where the instance has been installed. All the SQL Queries and procedures just have the local resource scope of what is there on the executing machine. Not the resources of your PC.
This i the trouble you have while executing your proc.